# Only Selecting Cases for all Time Periods

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal data set for a month in which there is some user attrition.

I'd like to subset the data just for those **users who are active across all 30 days**, but I could not find an example of this type of subset.  Here is an example of the data layout:

```
date          userID       x
2001-11-08    1            20
2001-11-08    2            2
2001-11-08    3            10
2001-11-08    4            5
2001-11-08    5            1
2001-11-09    1            19
2001-11-09    3            4
2001-11-09    4            5
...
2001-11-30    1            15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subset(dnow, ave(as.numeric(date), userID, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))==30)
```

Comment: Very clean, and it allows me to keep the full dataset. I would have to do a merge with the plyr() example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the data processing tools in the plyr library.

```
library(plyr)

startdate <- ISOdate(2011, 1, 1)
userdata <- data.frame(
        date = startdate + rep(1:31, each=3),
        userID = 1 + round(9*runif(93)),
        x = round(100*runif(93))
)

summary <- ddply(userdata, .(userID), summarize, activedays=length(date))
summary[summary$activedays >= 30, ]
```

You can find out more about plyr at Hadley's excellent website: http://had.co.nz/plyr/

Comment: What about  subset(ddply(userdata, .(userID), mutate, activedays=length(date)), activedays==30, select=-activedays)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ave` to determine the number of days each user was active per month.

```
Data$activeDays <- ave(Data$userID, Data$userID, FUN=length)
Data[ Data$activeDays >= 30, ]
```

It would be a bit more tricky if your data set contains multiple months...

Answer (score -1):

```
which(tapply(userdata$date, userdata$userID, length) == 30)
```

Comment: This will not work. Take a look at the output of the tapply call.

Comment: Oops. The tapply part was fine but then I broke it by slapping brackets around it.

Comment: this still does not work. tapply will return a vector of user counts by user, in the order of user. It would have to be something like: 
subset(userdata, userID%in%names(which(tapply(date, userID, length)==30)))